# How can we use an ID from database as Listview ID using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android, sql

I am new to Android and started to work on databases and listview. I want to use subjectID as an ID of the listview I created. So that I can use that ID to query records from database when an item is tapped. I know this is asked many times but nothing seems to work on me. Thanks in advance for the help.

Part of the SQL: subjectID as _id

I have this piece of codes:

```
 String[] dataColumns = { "subjectName","shortemail", "lastScanDate", "lastScore" } ;
int[] viewIDs = { R.id.list_column1 , R.id.list_column2, R.id.list_column3, R.id.list_column4  }; 


SimpleCursorAdapter adapter
        = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                  this,                             // The Context for the ListView
                  R.layout.subject_line,          // Points to the XML for a list item
                  cursor,                           // The cursor to get items from
                  dataColumns,
                  viewIDs
          );


    setListAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();



public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

//codes here

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass the row_id to next activity in onItemClick() event so that you can fetch records of that particular id, Am i right ??

Comment: @shree202 - You are right. I want to pass that ID to next activity that displays the records with that subjectID.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the sourcecode of CursorAdapter, you can find:

```
   public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
            } else {
                return 0;
           }
        } else {
           return 0;
       }
    }
```

And `mRowIDColumn` is assigned:

```
 mRowIDColumn = cursorPresent ? c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id") : -1;
```

These mean, if you use "_id" as your database id, `getItemId()` will be already the database's Id.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the row_ids and store in an `ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>;`

Then in your `onItemClick()` insert this code:

```
row_id = arraylist.get(position);

startActivity(new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class).putExtra("row_id", row_id));
```

Hope this will help you.
If you need further help just let me know.

This is not the only way, we can achieve this. It is the simplest way.